# Is there any effective automatic interface test?

Tags: javascript, html, css, automated-tests, frontend

I worked with C# and I wrote effective automated tests for my code, tests that would give me guarantees the heart of our business that are features of the system.

Now I'm working in an advertising agency and now our big problems are interface/design problems like misaligned elements, colors, text fonts, javascript features like fadeIn/fadeOut and slideIn/slideOut elements, css problems like overlapping elements with `z-index`, and so on...

Tools like Selenium/WatiN not suitable for me because these tools are to test functionality. Not the design (HTML, CSS) itself. HTML/CSS/Javascript together in design (not functionality) are fragile.

Today, the best way to test HTML/CSS/Javascript together in design is a manual test: a human being looking for errors on page.

There is an effective way to test such things automatically?

Comment: So you want a program that opens every browser, tries your page and reports back to you with any errors that it finds, including misaligned elements and incorrect z-indexes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to test dynamic things such as fade-ins and fade-outs, but the static layout can be checked, IMHO, in a strightforward manner. As a rule, you should have a design (make-up, mokup) as an image for every page. Then you use Selenium or other automation tool to take snapshots of every page and compare them with corresponding designs. Ideally there should be pixel-by-pixel matching, but you can admin some tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

There are validators that you can put in place to validate these.

Examples:
HTML ( http://validator.w3.org/ )

CSS ( http://csslint.net/ )

JS  ( http://www.jslint.com)

There is no real way to test these all "as a whole".  The reason being is HTML and CSS are visual "presentation" layers.  Within these languages different browsers depending on their versions can render elements, actions, events, and more differently.  Trust me, this is a big frustration as front-end developers.

Most JavaScript frameworks out now boast all mainstream browser support (IE6+, FFOX, Chrome , Safari, Opera, etc)

This is a site that will inform you what is compatible with HTML5 and CSS3:
http://findmebyip.com/litmus

Again, sorry but there is no way (at least that I know of to just globally "test") all these things.

JsLint as mentioned above is probably the closest thing you are refering to as far as being able to test in an environment.  It does not however, check your HTML or CSS with congruence with JavaScript syntax with the expected result of proper displays.

Because of how wonky browsers have been over the years and lack of standards compliance there is no "universal" testing method.

If you want to just "test" how a site looks in "every single known browser" you're going to want to look at something like this:
http://browsershots.org/

however, it will not test your Javascript.